# Unselect all listview checkboxes

Tags: android, listview, android-checkbox

I have a custom listview for showing name and mobile numbers from contacts. The listview has checkboxes in row layout as well as "Select All" header checkbox. When I select header checkbox all listview checkboxes get checked (except those which doesn't have + sign before their number). Now problem is I'm not able to uncheck them when I unselect header checkbox.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    ListView list;
    Button btnDone;
    CustomAdapter adapter;
    CheckBox selectAll;
    ArrayList<Contacts> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_contacts_chooser);
        btnDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_done);
        selectAll = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.selectAll);

        fetchContacts();

        adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.contact_item,arrayList, selectAll);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void fetchContacts(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M ){
            askForPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,1100);
        }else{
            new LoadContactsAyscn().execute();
        }
    }

    private void askForPermission(String permission, Integer requestCode) {
        System.out.println("sammy_reached_askForPermission");
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, permission)) {
                // if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission)) {  // for fragment

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
                // requestPermissions(new String[]{permission}, requestCode);  // for fragment

            } else {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
                // requestPermissions(new String[]{permission}, requestCode); // for fragment
            }
        } else {
            new LoadContactsAyscn().execute();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        System.out.println("sammy_reached_onRequestPermissionsResult");
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if(requestCode==1100){
                new LoadContactsAyscn().execute();
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private class LoadContactsAyscn extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Contacts>> {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Contacts> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            System.out.println("sammy_reached_LoadContactsAyscn");
            String name;
            String phone = null;
            String emailContact = null;

            if (arrayList != null) arrayList.clear();

            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    Contacts model = new Contacts();
                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                        System.out.println("Contact Name: " + name);
                        Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {

                            phone = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                            System.out.println("Contact Phone: " + phone);

                        }
                        pCur.close();
                        Cursor emailCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                        while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                            emailContact = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

                            System.out.println("Contact Email: " + emailContact);
                        }
                        emailCur.close();
                    }
                    model.setName(name);
                    model.setMobile(phone);
                    model.setEmail(emailContact);
                    if(phone.contains("+"))
                        model.setPlus(true);
                    else
                        model.setPlus(false);
                    arrayList.add(model);

                }
            }



            return arrayList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Contacts> contacts) {
            // super.onPreExecute(contacts);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }





}



public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contacts> {

    private Context mContext;
    int resource;
    private CheckBox selectAll;
    private ArrayList<Contacts> arrayList = new ArrayList<Contacts>();

    public CustomAdapter(Context mContext, int resource, ArrayList<Contacts> arrayList, CheckBox selectAll) {
        super(mContext, resource, arrayList);
        this.resource = resource;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.selectAll = selectAll;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();

            v = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

            holder.tvName  = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            holder.tvMobEmail = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvMobEmail);
            holder.chkbox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.chkbox);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        final Contacts item = arrayList.get(position);

        holder.tvName.setText(item.getName());
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getMobile()))
            holder.tvMobEmail.setText(item.getEmail());
        else
            holder.tvMobEmail.setText(item.getMobile());


        holder.chkbox.setChecked(item.isChecked());
        holder.chkbox.setTag(position);
        /*holder.chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                   //item.setChecked(true);
                    holder.chkbox.setChecked(true);
                }else{
                    //item.setChecked(false);
                    holder.chkbox.setChecked(false);
                }

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });*/

        selectAll.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                System.out.println("sammy_SelectAllBox "+isChecked);
                System.out.println("Total Size: "+getCount());
                System.out.println("Checked Size: "+getCheckedCount());
                if(isChecked){
                    for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
                        if(arrayList.get(i).isPlus())
                            arrayList.get(i).setChecked(true);
                        else
                            arrayList.get(i).setChecked(false);
                    }
                    selectAll.setText("Unselect All");
                }else{

                        System.out.println("Total Size: "+arrayList.size());
                        System.out.println("Checked Size: "+getCheckedCount());
                        for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
                            //if(arrayList.get(i).isPlus())
                            arrayList.get(i).setChecked(false);
                        }


                    selectAll.setText("Select All");
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });


        return v;
    }

    class ViewHolder {

        TextView tvName, tvMobEmail;
        CheckBox chkbox;
    }

    private int getCheckedCount(){
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
            if (arrayList.get(i).isChecked()){
                count++;
            }
        }

        return count;

    }
}
```

Comment: where you getting problem in this code? if(arrayList.size()==getCheckedCount()){
                        System.out.println("Total Size: "+arrayList.size());
                        System.out.println("Checked Size: "+getCheckedCount());
                        for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
                            //if(arrayList.get(i).isPlus())
                            arrayList.get(i).setChecked(false);
                        }

                    }

Comment: if(arrayList.size()==getCheckedCount()) this condition going true when you uncheck selectall?

Comment: I don't think that condition is going true. But when I remove that line the function for header checkbox works ok but I'm not able to check or uncheck individual listview checkboxes. They get checked or unchecked as per the condition of header checkbox. @Zaki

Comment: try after removing this condition 
 
if(arrayList.size()==getCheckedCount()). because if this condition not going true then it cant helps. You are adding all items in your arrayList so how you get true when you do 
 
if(arrayList.size()==getCheckedCount())?

Comment: hope you understand what i am describing. e.g arrayList.size() is 10 and getCheckedCount() is only the checked size.

Comment: I updated my  code. Please have a look. After removing the line ` if(arrayList.size()==getCheckedCount())` and also commenting out listview checkbox changelistener almost everything works. Only problem is I need to make those numbers uncheckable which don't have "+" sign. In my current code I can individually check any checkbox which should not be the case. Let me know if there is any problem understing.

Comment: I cant understand what you are trying to say. But     //if(arrayList.get(i).isPlus())
remove this comment hope it helps

Comment: you want to say that the number those don't have "+" sign will be checked bydefault? and user can't uncheck that number? is it right?

Comment: No. Those nos which don't have "+" sign will always remain unselected even if user tries to select them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136121/discussion-between-sammy-and-zaki-pathan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change it like this.

```
holder.chkbox.setChecked(item.isChecked());
```

to

```
if(item.isChecked())
    holder.chkbox.setChecked(item.isChecked());
else
    holder.chkbox.setEnabled(false);
```

in the adapter class.

> You have to try selectAll check box in main activity. And its listener
>   too. because selectAll doesn't need in adapter class. And in activity
>   after select all listener use the adapter because modified data should
>   be go to adapter

Edit

if you want to deselect if any item get unchecked then use

in the getView()

```
if(item.isChecked()) {
            holder.chkbox.setEnabled(true);
            holder.chkbox.setChecked(item.isChecked());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }else{

            if(item.isPlus()){
                holder.chkbox.setEnabled(true);
                holder.chkbox.setChecked(item.isChecked());

            }else{

                holder.chkbox.setChecked(false);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
     holder.chkbox.setTag(position);


holder.chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                if(!item.isPlus()){
                    if(!selectAll.isChecked()){
                        holder.chkbox.setChecked(false);
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please add +", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        holder.chkbox.setChecked(false);
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please add + before", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

As per sammy help and suggestion

Comment: First, `arrayList.get(i).setEnabled` is not a setter from model class. So how to use it. Also what about individual listview checkbox changelistener? @CoDFather

Comment: https://www.hastebin.com/arubereruk.cs  This is the model class @ CoDFather

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136123/discussion-between-sammy-and-codfather).

Answer (score 0):

Changed your setOnCheckedChangeListener

```
        selectAll.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                System.out.println("sammy_SelectAllBox "+isChecked);
                System.out.println("Total Size: "+getCount());
                System.out.println("Checked Size: "+getCheckedCount());
                if(isChecked){
                    for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
                        arrayList.get(i).setChecked(false);
                    }
                    selectAll.setText("Unselect All");
                }else{
                    for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
                      arrayList.get(i).setChecked(true);
                    }
                    selectAll.setText("Select All");
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
```

Comment: This is no good as when I select header checkbox, all listview checkboxes gets selected and vice versa @user2025187